# Как узнать какая кнопка была нажата?

Tags: android, kotlin

Как в котлине можно узнать какая кнопка была нажата? Что-то типа onClick в джаве

Comment: Пишешь код на java, копируешь его, вставляешь в код Kotlin. Андроид Студио его конвертирует как нужно. Profit

Answer (score 2):

[Вопрос на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60037634)

**Способ №1**

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    // Do some work here
}
```

**Способ №2**

```
button.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        // Do some work here
    }
})
```

**Способ №3**

```
button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { view ->
    // Do some work here
})
```

**Способ №4**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener{

    lateinit var button : Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        button = findViewById(R.id.button1)
        button.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        when(view?.id){
            R.id.button1->{
                // do some work here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Способ №5**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    lateinit var button : Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        button = findViewById(R.id.button1)
        button.setOnClickListener(listener)
    }

    val listener= View.OnClickListener { view ->
        when (view.getId()) {
            R.id.button1 -> {
                // Do some work here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*p.s. ответ - общий*